# I am the person who abides by rules, but breaks the rules. Who am I?

Tags: riddle

> I am the person who abides by the rules, yet sometimes breaks the rules.
>
> I discuss with everyone about their problems late at night, but I forget to give a solution in the morning.
>
> I don't compel anyone to taste me, yet when someone tastes me they want to eat me more.
>
> I am treated badly by many people, yet the same people like me when they are in distress.
>
> *Who am I?*

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are:

> Alcohol/Beer

I am the person who abides by the rules, yet some times breaks the rules.

> We can drink alcohol, but too much of it and it breaks the rules of driving/public

I discuss with everyone about their problems late at night, but I forget to give a solution in the morning.

> People discuss their issues over a drink, but it never gives an answer or solves the problem

I don't compel anyone to taste me, yet when someone tastes me they want to eat me more.

> No one is forced to drink, but people usually want more when they've had one drink

I am treated badly by many people, yet the same people like me when they are in distress.

> Alcohol is misused by many, and people turn to it in their times of distress

Comment: excellent! right answer

Answer (score 7):

Are you:

> God (in Christianity)?

I am the person who abides by the rules, yet some times breaks the rules.

> God is supposed to follow the rules they created, but sometimes had a little deal with the devil (see Book of Job) and broke the rules.

I discuss with everyone about their problems late at night, but I forget to give a solution in the morning.

> People pray to God before going to bed but never actually get a reply.

I don't compel anyone to taste me, yet when someone tastes me they want to eat me more.

> This might be to do with the act of communion? When Christians eat wafers and drink wine meant to symbolise the body and blood of Jesus (who was supposedly God in human form).

I am treated badly by many people, yet the same people like me when they are in distress.

> There are a lot of atheists who do not believe, but still find themselves pleading with God when they are distressed.

Comment: +1 because this is also what I first thought. *"I am the person who abides by the rules, yet some times breaks the rules."* doesn't really fit though, because God creates the rules, and *"I don't compel anyone to taste me, yet when someone tastes me they want to eat me more."* doesn't fit particularly well either, so this may not be the answer...

Comment: @JamesDouglas Religions commonly break each other's rules, so I think that part is fine.  "they want to eat me more" also works passably as a metaphor for religious conversion (though, not everyone who tries the religion chooses to convert).

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you are:

> A lawyer (or a politition)

I am the person who abides by the rules, yet some times breaks the rules.

> Lawyers abide/immerse themselves in the rules, and sometimes break the rules.

I discuss with everyone about their problems late at night, but I forget to give a solution in the morning.

> Lawyers talk a lot to people about their problems but don't always give solutions

I don't compel anyone to taste me, yet when someone tastes me they want to eat me more.

> People who start working in the law do it more and more(?)

I am treated badly by many people, yet the same people like me when they are in distress.

> Lawyers are joked about as being fraudulent, but when people are in financial trouble they hire lawyers.

Answer (score 4):

Are you

> Death?

I am the person who abides by the rules, yet some times breaks the rules.

> Everyone dies, but some people "cheat" death

I discuss with everyone about their problems late at night, but I forget to give a solution in the morning.

> When left in your own thoughts, most people think about death and how to escape it, but there is no escaping death.

I don't compel anyone to taste me, yet when someone tastes me they want to eat me more.

> This may be a little morbid, but could this be referring to the rush of near-death experiences? Thrill seekers try to tempt fate as much as possible because they taste death.

I am treated badly by many people, yet the same people like me when they are in distress.

> No one wants to die, which is why everyone hates talking about death. However, when someone is feeling down and out, they feel their only escape is death.

Answer (score 3):

You are

> Fear

I am the person who abides by the rules, yet some times breaks the rules.

> Fear is perfectly reasonable; to warn you about danger and get you away fast (see adrenaline), but sometimes doesn't makes much sense, like fear of spiders.

I discuss with everyone about their problems late at night, but I forget to give a solution in the morning.

> People are often afraid of the dark, but it is forgotten in the morning(?)

I don't compel anyone to taste me, yet when someone tastes me they want to eat me more.

> People can become addicted to scaring themselves; see horror movies.

I am treated badly by many people, yet the same people like me when they are in distress.

> Fear is looked down upon, but those same people are afraid when they are in distress

Answer (score 2):

Could it be

> Sleep?

I am the person who abides by the rules, yet some times breaks the rules.

> I think "person" shouldn't really be here, but I would say the rule is that people sleep at night, even though this doesn't always happen

I discuss with everyone about their problems late at night, but I forget to give a solution in the morning.

> Sleep is said to help resolve a lot of problems, but people usually wake up in the morning, so sleep cannot give a solution then.

I don't compel anyone to taste me, yet when someone tastes me they want to eat me more.

> People usually sleep when they need it, not when they want to. Then again, once someone starts sleeping, they won't stop soon.

I am treated badly by many people, yet the same people like me when they are in distress.

> "Sleep is for the weak" people often say these days. But when they are in distress, they want to rest/take a break/forget about it and sleep is one such way to achieve it.

Comment: Very good.  But that is not the exact answer even though it matches the riddle.

Answer (score 1):

> A flirt, or very casual dater

I am the person who abides by the rules, yet some times breaks the rules.

> There are rules in the game of love, but sometimes you have to make the first move Sadie Hawkins style

I discuss with everyone about their problems late at night, but I forget to give a solution in the morning.

> We talked about it late at night, but there's no relationship there, in the cold light of day

I don't compel anyone to taste me, yet when someone tastes me they want to eat me more.

> good kisser (PG version, heynow!)

I am treated badly by many people, yet the same people like me when they are in distress.

> dumped and rebound, again and again

Who am I?

Answer (score 1):

Are you

> Excuse?

I am the person who abides by the rules, yet some times breaks the rules.

> Some excuses are reasonable. Some are not.

I discuss with everyone about their problems late at night, but I forget to give a solution in the morning.

> You can use a excuse while discussing a problem. But it solves nothing.

I don't compel anyone to taste me, yet when someone tastes me they want to eat me more.

> Everyone knows they are not so useful. But some people find excuses again and again.

I am treated badly by many people, yet the same people like me when they are in distress.

> Nobody likes others using excuses. Some people hate that. But what else could they do if they had the same problems?